# Failed to Run Query: Exception in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm building a laravel application where there is a controller which functionality is we have to book a classroom where if a time has already booked or there in database we can't book a classroom in that time interval. I have used the following controller :

```
public function postAllocateRoom(Request $request)
    {

            $classRoom = new ClassRoom();  

            $classRoom->department_id=$request->Input(['department_id']);     
            $classRoom->room_id=$request->Input(['room_id']); 
            $classRoom->course_id=$request->Input(['course_id']); 
            $classRoom->day_id=$request->Input(['day_id']); 
            $classRoom->start=$request->Input(['start']); 
            $classRoom->end=$request->Input(['end']);  
            $startTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'));
            $endTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('end'));
            $classRoom=DB::select('SELECT allocate_rooms.id 
            FROM allocate_rooms
            WHERE '.$startTime.' BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start AND allocate_rooms.end')->count(); 

            $messages ="Class Room Already Taken";
            if ($classRoom>0) {
             return redirect('allocateRoomPage');
                    }
            else { 
                 $classRoom->save();            
            return redirect('allocateRoomPage');  
            }                   
    }
```

But I'm getting following Error while saving in database:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '17:00:00 BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start
>   AND allocate_rooms.end' at line 3 (SQL: SELECT allocate_rooms.id  FROM
>   allocate_rooms WHERE 2016-05-08 17:00:00 BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start
>   AND allocate_rooms.end)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The date needs to be quoted as well:

```
$classRoom=DB::select('SELECT allocate_rooms.id 
FROM allocate_rooms
WHERE "' . $startTime . '" BETWEEN allocate_rooms.start AND allocate_rooms.end')->count();
```

---

I would suggest searching for a method to prepare MySQL queries in laravel, instead of writing them by hand.

Go through this blog post regarding the same: http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Comment: I have used your suggestion, but the problem is it's not saving the value which are contradict in database but it's saving 00:00:00 in database!

Comment: @RandeepSingh That is a logic issue. I have no idea about how your databases are designed, how you're trying to insert/update values etc. I'd suggest creating a new question, as a followup to this one, and describe the issue clearly.